# Exception with MS-SQL Server,JDBC and XA Transactions

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm getting the following exception in my log when I try to perform an XA transaction:

> javax.transaction.xa.XAException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc_SQLServerException: failed to create the XA control connection. Error: "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_sqljdbc_xa_init_ex', database 'master' schema 'dbo'

I followed these tutorials [Understanding XA Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335.aspx) and [How to make MSSQL Server XA Datasource Work?](http://www.senthilb.com/2010/01/how-to-make-xa-datasource-work-in-mssql.html)
After following the first tutorial I also ran the following command in SSMS:

> use master GO
>   EXEC sp_addrolemember [SqlJDBCXAUser], 'MyUserName' GO

I'll also add that I ran

> use master GO EXEC sp_grantdbaccess 'MyUserName','MyUserName' GO

to verify that the user has access to the master db and I got an error that "the user already exists in the current database".
Lastly I verified, via SSMS, that the role `SqlJDBCXAUser` does have EXECUTE granted in regard to `xp_sqljdbc_xa_init_ex`.
The DB I'm using is obviously not `master` but `myDBName`.
The only correlation between the two, with regard to this issue, is that `MyUserName` is the owner of `myDBName` and exists as a user in `master`.
My Server is running on Windows XP SP3 (so the hotfix mentioned in the first tutorial is not relevant as it is meant for XP SP2 and under, I know as I tried to run the hotfix).

Has someone encountered this issue? I'd really appreciate some leads.
Thanks,
Ittai

**Update:**
I've looked at the first tutorial, from `Microsoft`, again and there are two paragraphs which I'm not sure what they mean and they might contain the solution:

> Execute the database script xa_install.sql on every SQL Server instance that will participate in distributed transactions. This script installs the extended stored procedures that are called by sqljdbc_xa.dll. These extended stored procedures implement distributed transaction and XA support for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver. You will need to run this script as an administrator of the SQL Server instance.

When they say `SQL Server instance`, do they mean the sql server which contains several databases, including `master` and `myDBName`(I'm used to oracle terms which are a bit different)? I ran the `xa_install.sql` script once as it was given and it states `use master`.

This is the second paragraph:

> *Configuring the User-Defined Roles*
>   To grant permissions to a specific user to participate in distributed transactions with the JDBC driver, add the user to the SqlJDBCXAUser role. For example, use the following Transact-SQL code to add a user named 'shelby' (SQL standard login user named 'shelby') to the SqlJDBCXAUser role:

```
USE master  
GO  
EXEC sp_grantdbaccess 'shelby', 'shelby'  
GO  
EXEC sp_addrolemember [SqlJDBCXAUser], 'shelby'
```

> SQL user-defined roles are **defined per database**. To create your own role for security purposes, you will have to define the role in each database, and add users in a per database manner. **The SqlJDBCXAUser role is strictly defined in the master database** because it is used to grant access to the SQL JDBC extended stored procedures that reside in master. You will have to first grant individual users access to master, and then grant them access to the SqlJDBCXAUser role while you are logged into the master database.

I'm not sure but I think that the above bolded sentence says that the `SqlJDBCXAUser` role should only be defined on `master` and that other users which access `myDBName` should be granted access to `master` and then added to the role and that will **somehow**(don't know how) will enable them when using the `myDBName` database to use the xa packages.

**Update 2:**
This is a screenshot from SSMS of the stored procedure's security settings under the SqlJDBCXAUser role
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We only had to do the following:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE USER [UserName] FOR LOGIN [UserName] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
use [master]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_commit] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_end] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_forget] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_forget_ex] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_init] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_init_ex] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_prepare] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_prepare_ex] TO [UserName] 
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_recover] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_rollback] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_rollback_ex] TO [UserName]
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[xp_sqljdbc_xa_start] TO [UserName]
GO
```

Comment: Wow! This actually worked! Thank you. The strange thing is that I performed a variation of these commands (as part of MS tutorial they are part of xa_install.sl) with the only difference being that I granted the permissions to a role and added my user to the role. Do you know perhaps why this occurred? I would be very gratefull.

Comment: This also worked for me , thanks ! - I think the Microsoft should update their docs to make them a little more comprehensive and fool-proof.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've used Java with SQL server, but just off the bat I noticed something in your T-SQL that might not have behaved the way you wanted.  The snippet:

```
use master GO;
EXEC sp_addrolemember [SqlJDBCXAUser], 'MyUserName' GO;
```

Only applies the [SqlJDBCXAUser] to your username in the master database.  If your database is in another instance, you will also have to add the role there.  The other I'm assuming was a typo ('sp_gratdbaccess' should be 'sp_grantdbaccess').

I'm assuming your 'xa_install.sql' scripts that you had to run in all participating servers ran successfully, and you received no error messages?  Examine the script for the roles it defines, just to make sure what you are typing matches what is needed.

**Update:**

Just some sanity checks:

- Is SQL Server on a Windows XP (why?) server? then you have a hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922668
- Is SQL Server on a Windows 2003 box with Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC)? the you have a hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899756
- Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335.aspx for other limitations you might be running into: particularly if you are using MS DTC.

Microsoft is ambiguous when it calls things an "Instance", particularly because they apply it to database instances (your database) as well as SQL Server instances.  One physical server can have multiple copies of SQL server running at the same time listening on different ports.  Each of these would have its own Master database instance.  By the context of the other statements (i.e. the XA transaction support lives in the master database), they are talking about every copy of SQL Server you have running.  If your app's database is spread accross 4 instances (installations) of SQL Server, you have to perform the XA installation steps on all four installations.

The last step to make sure that the roles took, and are applied to your system properly, open up the master database with the management console.  You want to make sure your user is in the Databases/master/Security/Users folder, and that it has the SqlJDBCXAUser role enabled (checkbox for the role).

Next, go to the offending stored procedure that is complaining, and make sure that any security settings include the SqlJDBCXAUser role.  The role names *shouldn't* be case sensitive (as SQL itself is not), but it wouldn't hurt to make sure the role case is the same case--just in case.

If that fails, also run the 'xa_install.sql' script in your MyDatabase instance.  I personally hate this ambiguity, but it very well could be what they mean.  But before you do that, make sure you don't need any hot fixes or have a configuration where it won't work right.  Undoing something a complicated SQL script does can be a major pain.  That's why I suggest doing this last.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment. The typo is indeed a typo. There were no errors apart from the fact that the script (which is a microsoft issued script) tries to drop the relevant packages before adding them and thus states an error the first time because there is nothing to drop. Regarding your comment about the role not being applied to my username in `myDBName` I've added information above which led me to think this is what I need to do. If you can take a look at it and give me your input, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I've also updated my answer to add a couple other things to try.

Comment: The OS is Win XP-SP3 so the hotfix is not relevant (I tried to install it before but it says it's already installed as it's for SP2 under). I verified again that the role appears in the users of master and I'll post in a second in the question a screenshot of the permissions of the SqlJDBCXAUser role with respect to the stored procedure. If you'll agree that it looks proper I will sadly try running the xa_install.sql on myDB

Comment: Everything looks as the instructions imply.  I have a bit more information regarding SQL Server instances.  I've been working with auto-discovering an installed database, and SqlServer's API for the process lists the server name, the instance name, and a couple other params.  On my development box I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 and 2008 Express.  These are separate instances.  However it does not refer to the multiple databases installed on these instances.

Comment: Before you install the xa_install.sql in your databse instance, make sure that your user definition is in the global Security/Logins, has access to your myDatabase instance AND the master database instance.  As you are looking at the "User Mapping" tab, select both databases and ensure the proper roles are applied at this global level.