# Configuration of XA dataSources on Jboss eap 6.4 with sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, jboss-eap-6

I have configured the XA-datasources on sql server by the following ways:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Example_Microsoft_SQLServer_XA_Datasource.html

```
enter code here

  <datasources>
    <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/MyDataSource"    pool-name="SQLServerPool">
     <driver>sqlserver</driver>
     <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">localhost</xa-datasource-property>
     <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">mydb</xa-datasource-property>
     <xa-datasource-property name="SelectMethod">cursor</xa-datasource-property>
     <security>
     <user-name>admin</user-name>
     <password>admin</password>
     </security>
     <xa-pool>
     <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
   </xa-pool>
   <validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
     </validation>
    </xa-datasource>
    <drivers>
     <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft">
      <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
       </driver>
     </drivers>
   </datasources>
```

And enabled XA transaction database side by following

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

But the Database I have been using for my project is not a master database .Since XA-transactions are enabled on master, by default data is taking from master db and not from my database.
Is it that I need to configure XA-transactions on "my database" for the problem to be resolved?
How to give the server name under  inorder to fetch from "my database "

My loginUserName is the owner of both master schema and "mydatabase" schema and have created Role SqlJDBCXA user both in master and "mydatabase".

Referred the following but couldnot help
[Exception with MS-SQL Server,JDBC and XA Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043859/exception-with-ms-sql-server-jdbc-and-xa-transactions)

I'm using sqljdbc4.jar and driver class is "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
The JDBC jar is being detected in the jboss Management console and when i test it ,i'm getting the following error:

"failed to create JDBC connection.There are no running servers bound to this datasource"

Can anyone Suggest?
ThankYou

Comment: Do you have MySQL Server running on the same host you have WildFly running on?

Comment: The Jboss is running on domain mode.The MS Sql server and Jboss are running on different machines.The JDBC connection is succesfully connected and I could see that in JBoss Management console after making the following changes in      <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">ipaddress</xa-datasource-property>     and added properties like instance name and port name after referring to  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx